# Prevent changing indentation from tabs to spaces

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have VSCode installed and python 3.6.8
I use tabs for my indentation. But when ever I save the file, all the tabs are being converted to spaces.
This might be because of the formatter I use, i.e. **Black**. How do I prevent the formatter from doing that(Do all your formatting except *inter-changing indents with spaces*)?

Thank you

Comment: PEP8 is clear about using tabs for indentation: Tabs or Spaces?

Spaces are the preferred indentation method.

Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.

Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.

Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have VS Code set up to insert space into tabs, then Black will very likely replace them with spaces as that's the norm in the Python community and Black takes a very opinionated view on how to format Python code. You could try another formatter like yapf or autopep8 to see if they will leave physical tabs in.

But do note that the vast majority of the Python community uses spaces, so you are potentially facing an uphill battle.

Answer (score 4):

Pass in the argument `--ignore=W191` to `autopep8`, and it would ignore the *Indentation warning* of *indentation contains tabs*.

For VSCode, use the settings-entry `python.formatting.autopep8Args`.
[vscode-settings-entry-gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lszfT.png)

Answer (score 3):

Both `autopep8` and `black` are very strict.
They don't just *recommend* spaces over tabs, but *force* the usage of space indentation.

If you really want to use tabs, you should use `yapf`, with style `use_tabs=True`.

Comment: Moved to using '4 space', Thanks for the answers : ]

Comment: I was not able to get yapf with use_tabs=True to work.

Answer (score 3):

So one of the comments was that yapf is not so easy to get working. Under Debian, install

```
apt-get install yapf3
```

Now go to your source directory and run

```
yapf3 --style "google" --style-help > .style.yapf
```

Edit the .style.yapf so that you put

```
use_tabs=True
```

instead of False.

Now run

```
yapf3 -i dirty.py
```

and it really uses tabs for indentation. Spaces are still used but only for visual formatting not for indentation. I am sending a visual example how my code is formatted.

[image]

Comment: In order to use the style file with VSCode, either add a --style argument with an absolute link to the file in the settings or put it in the project root. I did the latter, and it works. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13643

Answer (score 2):

Until maintainers/contributors add a setting to be able to indent Python with tabs, I found a workaround to this issue by using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension.

Steps to fix the issue:

1. Install extension.
2. Find your `settings.json` and `keybindings.json`. From [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

   Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

   ```
    - Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
    - macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
    - Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
   ```
3. Add this to `settings.json`:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.properlyFormatAnyDocument",
        "sequence": [
            "editor.action.formatDocument",
            "editor.action.indentationToTabs"
        ]
    }
]
```

4. Add this to `keybindings.json`:

```js
{
    "key": "shift+alt+f",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
        "command": "multiCommand.properlyFormatAnyDocument"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

5. Save all files and it works.

---

Technically, [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) has `use_tabs` setting, but I was never able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not only 'black' but also 'autopep8' and 'yapf' will convert the tabs to spaces. And looks like both 'black', 'autopep8' and 'yapf' haven't provided args to change the format behavior of indent. And I agree with Brett Cannon, you'd better adapt to space indent.

If you really want a try of that, you can find the black.py in site-packages folder and at the lines of 1540 in black.py change the '    '(four spaces) to '    '(a tab, copy a tab, and you can choose any spaces of the tab contains). Then you can get what you want. But, I really don't recommend it.